# Importing modules from subdirectories

Tags: python, path, directory, python-import

I have a file structure like this:

```
package/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  subdir/
    bar.py
    baz.py
```

I want to be able to run `foo.py` and import `bar.py`. Inside `bar.py`, `baz.py` is imported using `import baz`. The problem is that `bar` is not able to import `baz` if I import it into `foo`.

**foo.py**

```
from importlib import import_module
import_module('subdir.bar', package='package')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need a `__init__.py` inside your `subdir` folder. See the example below and the output:

foo.py

```
from subdir import bar
print "hello from foo.py"
```

subdir/`__init__.py`

*(empty)*

subdir/bar.py

```
import baz
print "hello from bar.py"
```

subdir/baz.py

```
print "hello from baz.py"
```

output of running `foo.py`

> ```
> hello from baz.py
> hello from bar.py
> hello from foo.py
> ```

Comment: For anything to be import-able module you need to have a __init__.py within it.